# How to extract specific values/fields from the text file?

Tags: text-processing

How to extract the following values/fields from the text file in Linux system:

```
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"
CreationTime="20190225094504"
SubscriberNumber=92705073362
```

Text file sample data is mentioned below:

```
2019-02-25 09:45:04.427 FAIL RETRY: Failed for request id: 11235993 Cause: userNotReachable Info: <undef> Code: 27,USSD RequestId=11235993 OriginalId=11235993 EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000" CreationTime="20190225094504" ResendCount=0 Timestamp=1551071704342 (Mon Feb 25 09:45:04 AFT 2019) State=STATE_SENT SubscriberNumber=92705073362 UssdText=Last event was charged 687.95 MB from 3GB Monthly, Main Account 6.00 PKR, Remaining data 2,388.75 MB (Exp 25.03.2019), Main Account 7.62 PKR1500 PKR = 32GB valid 30 Days, Dial *477*32*1#. NumberingPlan=1 Nadi=4 UssdFormat=2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using grep

```
$ grep -oE '(EventCorrelationId|CreationTime|SubscriberNumber)[^ ]*' textfile
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"
CreationTime="20190225094504"
SubscriberNumber=92705073362
```

#### Using awk

Try:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' '/^EventCorrelationId=/ || /^CreationTime=/ || /^SubscriberNumber=/' textfile
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"
CreationTime="20190225094504"
SubscriberNumber=92705073362
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS=' '`

  This tells awk to use a blank as the record separator.
- `/^EventCorrelationId=/ || /^CreationTime=/ || /^SubscriberNumber=/`

  This tells awk to print the record if it matches any of these three regular expressions.  Some notes:

  - In a regex, `^` means beginning-of-the-record.  Thus `/^CreationTime=/` means a record that starts with `CreationTime=`
  - In awk, like many languages, `||` means logical-or.  Thus `^EventCorrelationId=/ || /^CreationTime=/` is true if either regex is matched.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -En 's/.*(EventCorrelationId=[^ ]*).*(CreationTime=[^ ]*).*(SubscriberNumber=[^ ]*).*/\1\n\2\n\3/p' textfile
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"
CreationTime="20190225094504"
SubscriberNumber=92705073362
```

#### Using an alternate separator in the output

To use `|` as the output separator in place of newline:

```
$ sed -En 's/.*(EventCorrelationId=[^ ]*).*(CreationTime=[^ ]*).*(SubscriberNumber=[^ ]*).*/\1|\2|\3/p' textfile
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"|CreationTime="20190225094504"|SubscriberNumber=92705073362
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -Eo '(EventCorrelationId|CreationTime|SubscriberNumber)=[^ ]+' file
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"
CreationTime="20190225094504"
SubscriberNumber=92705073362
```

- `grep -Eo` grep in extended regular expression mode (less escaping of special chars) and print only the matched parts
- `(EventCorrelationId|CreationTime|SubscriberNumber)` match EventCorrelationId or CreationTime or SubscriberNumber
- `=[^ ]+` followed by "=", followed by non-space-character one or more times

**Edit1:**

Now separated by "|":

```
$ echo $(grep -Eo '(EventCorrelationId|CreationTime|SubscriberNumber)=[^ ]+' file) | tr ' ' '|'
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"|CreationTime="20190225094504"|SubscriberNumber=92705073362
```

**Edit2:**

Now separated by "|" in reversed order using `tac`:

```
$ echo $(grep -Eo '(EventCorrelationId|CreationTime|SubscriberNumber)=[^ ]+' file | tac) | tr ' ' '|'
SubscriberNumber=92705073362|CreationTime="20190225094504"|EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"
```

Comment: hanks for your kind support, using your (Using sed) command, I was able to extract the information. However, kindly to please suggest how to extract the mentioned values in one single line separated by "|" sign as shown below?

SubscriberNumber=92705073362|CreationTime="20190225094504"|EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"

Comment: Example added. But I didn't use sed :)

Answer (score 0):

I Tried with below awk method and it worked fine

```
j=`awk '{print NF}' filename `
for ((i=1;i<=$j;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" '$i ~ /EventCorrelationId/||$i ~ /CreationTime/||$i ~ /SubscriberNumber/{print $i}' filename ; done
```

output

```
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"
CreationTime="20190225094504"
SubscriberNumber=9270507336
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this exercise bu building up your regex dynamically, based on the fields you want outputted:

```
$ perl -lne '
   $re = join "|", map { +quotemeta } qw/EventCorrelationId CreationTime SubscriberNumber/;
   print join "|",  /(?:$re)=\H+/g;
' input.file
```

**Output:**

```
EventCorrelationId="615-493|-1899671563||1550927718000"|CreationTime="20190225094504"|SubscriberNumber=92705073362
```

**Working:**

- The fields that you want output are placed in an anonymous array `qw/.../`.
- Then we transform each of them using `map { ... }` by joining with logical OR `|`.
- In the last step, we apply the regex just constructed on the current record, `$_`, and the fields fished out are joined via the pipe symbol `|` to get the output.